# Crystal Reports: How to lock the order of an area chart legend and chart itself

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-xi

So I have created a chart that shows the amount of different priority calls that my team has taken over the past 3 months for each subtype.

The X axis shows dates, and the Y axis shows amount of calls taken. There are four priorities (p1,p2,p3,p4), and these are represented by the areas on the graph. I want the priorities to show in the order p1,p2,p3,p4 but instead they are showing in varying order over the the different subtypes.

How do I lock the priorities in the order that I want?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the chart → open Chart Expert → go to the Data tab

Your call priorities should be listed in the upper-right hand corner in the "On change of" box. Click on the "TopN..." button and verify that "No Sort" is selected. Now go back to the previous screen and now choose the "Order..." button.

By default, your priorities should be sorted in ascending order. If that is not working, you may want to consider putting it in specified order which will allow you to explicitly "lock in" the order that you want these to appear. Keep in mind that in a Stacked Area Chart, the specified order is actually bottom to top which is somewhat counter-intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for your input Ryan, this works as a whole but I find that when one of the priorities doesn't appear until a date later than the first it appears on top, so say 4 didn't appear until the second month it would show as:  
  
p4  
p1  
p2  
p3

Comment: Then you've got a chart setting somewhere that is overriding your specified order. I'd verify that your date element is set to "No Sort..." as well under the "TopN..." options and is set to regular ascending order.